# Filter ls output based on file size

Tags: command-line, bash, ls

I want to filter the output of the `ls` command based on file size. Any .jpg or .png files greater than 100KB should be reported in the output.

I've been able to filter the .png / .jpg files, but I'm not able to discard any files smaller than 100KB.

Here is what I'm currently using:

```
ls -lah | grep '.png\|.jpg'
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have suggested, `find` will allow you to find files in specified size ranges. `Find` outputs just the path to each file, though.  Also, without further qualification, `find` will find all the files in the current directory and in every directory below the current directory. The following searches only the current directory and uses `ls` to dispaly the results.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -size +200 \( -name \*.png -o -name \*.jpg \) -print | xargs ls -ldh
```

Note that the size is in blocks, where a block is often if not always 512 bytes.

Comment: You should mention that 'ls' must have the '-d' flag for this to work. 'ls -lh' will show the unfiltered output.

Comment: @cschol: The reason for the `-d` is to prevent `ls` from listing the contents of any directories in the output of `find`.

Answer (score 12):

You can do that using `find`:

```
find . -type f -size +100k | grep '.png\|.jpg'
```

Where `+100k` specifies the size in KB, meaning that only files larger than this should be output. `find` also has some other nice options, for example to only list files that were created a certain amount of time ago. See `man find` for more details.

The above could also be rewritten as

```
find . -type f -size +100k -name "*.png" -o -name "*.jpg"
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `find` instead of `ls`:

```
find . -type f -size +100k \( -name \*.png -or -name \*.jpg \)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using du

```
du -a --apparent-size -t +100k | grep '.png\|.jpg'
```